# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ prove $\int_{a}^{b}|f g| \leq\left(\max _{[a, b]}|f|\right) \int_{a}^{b}|g|$

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone help me with this proof? $\int_{a}^{b}|f g| \leq\left(\max _{[a, b]}|f|\right) \int_{a}^{b}|g|$. Intuitively it makes no sense to me because what if $f$ was just a line at lets say $2$, then wouldn't the integral on the bounds $a$, $b$ clearly be greater than just multiplying by the max of $f$?

Comment: If $f \equiv 2$, then the left-hand side is $\int_a^b 2|g|$ and the right-hand side is $2 \int_a^b |g|$.

Comment: "if f was just a line at lets say 2, then wouldnt the integral on the bounds a,b clearly be greater than just multiplying by the max of f" $-$ why do you think this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so trivial because, when we let $\max_{[a,b]}|f|=M$, then...

$$\int_a^b|fg|=\int_a^b|f||g|\le\int_a^bM|g|=M\int_a^b|g|$$